# unwanted programs in ALT+TAB window

Tags: windows-8.1

I experienced a little problem days ago and it still present. I have Windows 8.1 64bit English version with no "wierd" programs installed: I have Microsoft Office, Hyper-V enabled and that's all. Every time I switch on my computer and I go to the Networks Pane (where you can enable/disable wireless and connect to a wireless network choosing from the list) or I search for apps using WIN button and typing the program name I see that these two programs (Search Pane and Network Pane I just used) appears in my <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> window and they don't disappear.

I already cleaned the windows up: using ccleaner, hijackthis and using Disk Cleanup on my system partition. But all these actions didn't solve this annoying problem.

Does someone experienced this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce that here. The search results window appears at alt-tab, but not the search pane and not the Network pane.

Comment: That's why I posted a question... It is very wired... I also cannot reproduce it on my other computers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer** and delete setting named **AltTabSettings**.

Comment: Sergey! That solved my problem!